# order by with the number of correct condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have 16 condition.I want to `order by` at number of TRUE condition. that's mean the record with 16 TRUE condition be higher then the record with 15 TRUE condition.
if I do the following:

```
select * from tbluser
order by case 
when field1 like 'abc' AND field2 like 'aaa' AND ... field16 like 'bbb' then 1
when field1 like 'abc' AND field2 like 'aaa' AND ... field15 like 'ccc' then 2
.
.
.
when field2 like 'aaa' then 255
when field1 like 'abc' then 256
```

as you see, I should write 256 `when` that each of them has several condition.

considering the fact that just the number of correct condition is important and there is no other priority , is there a better solution?

Comment: You can move the logic as a new column called "score"  and you can order by that column. But its almost similar not beter. If you have a pattern of conditions there may be better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an ANSI SQL solution, you could just assign a true predicate 1, and false 0, and add up the conditions, and order by this descending:

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN Field1 LIKE 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Field2 LIKE 'aaa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        ...
        CASE WHEN Field16 LIKE 'bbb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC;
```

Since it is MySQL you can take a slight shortcut since it allows addition on booleans:

```
ORDER BY (Field1 LIKE 'abc') + (Field2 LIKE 'aaa') ... + (Field16 LIKE 'bbb') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but it sounds like you just want to order on an aggreated field....so here's a simple example of doing so.....

Create table #tmp (f1 int, f2 bit)
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  1, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  1, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  1, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  2, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  2, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  3, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  4, 1
INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT  4, 1

SELECT f1, count(f2)
FROM #tmp
WHERE f2 = 1  --TRUE
GROUP BY f1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1

You'll have to decide on rules for if the counts are equal.